# managing target definition

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have a core plugin that has custom core JFace and SWT implementations. UI plugin depends on core plugin and uses core plugin using target definition via update site. Everything works fine. However, I have core an ui plugins building in Jenkins and UI plugin job has dependency on core plugin job so that when core is rebuild, UI is rebuilt as well. Here is the thing, if I use 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT as version in core's POM, core's version in target definition is defined with the latest core version. So if add core to target definition with 0.0.1-20130405, build will work fine, but if I rebuild core tomorrow the version in target definition will not match with the version that core will have - 0.0.1-20130405 vs 0.0.1-20130406. I will have to manually re-add software update site for core in target definition.

Is there a way to manage target definition so it updates with latest core. Perhaps there is another way of doing what I need that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases - including a target definition -  you can specify the special version number 0.0.0 to mean give me the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. I know that this is possible for feature dependencies, but didn't know that TP also allows it.